# Post data to website using Python requests library

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to make a simple webscaper using *Python* and the `requests` library.

```
r=requests.get(https://nustar.newcastle.edu.au/psp/CS9PRD/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/MANAGE_ACADEMIC_RECORDS.STDNT_ACTIVATION.GBL?FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.HCSR_RECORDS_AND_REGISTRATION.HCSR_STUDENT_TERM_INFORMATION.HC_STDNT_ACTIVATION_GBL&IsFolder=false&IgnoreParamTempl=FolderPath%2cIsFolder
```

I would like to POST a search input into this URL, but I'm struggling to work out how.

This is the search box code from the website:

```
<input id="STDNT_SRCH_EMPLID" class="PSEDITBOX" type="text" maxlength="11" style="width:140px; " value="" tabindex="13" name="STDNT_SRCH_EMPLID"></input>
```

I assume I have to somehow change `value = ""` to `value = "foo"`.

Any help will appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See `request`'s quick start [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/).

```
import requests
value1='foo'
payload = {'STDNT_SRCH_EMPLID': value1} # 'key2': 'value2' and so on (comma delimited)
r = requests.post("http://yourUrl.org/", data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Using the Requests Library in Python: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Do a network analysis in the developer tool of your browser and copy the curl command of the POST package.

Then you surf to [curl.trillworks.com][1] and convert the curl command by pasting it into a Python POST request.

Inside of your python request you can modify the values.